# dgrid ColumnHider: disabling the hide columns menu?

Tags: javascript, dgrid

I have a dgrid with a permanently hidden column that needs to be there, because I need to filter the table on its values. I am using ColumnHider in order to hide it and it works fine.

However, using ColumnHider also shows the small "+" button in the table corner that is used to hide/show columns, and I really don't want that button to show (hiding/showing columns is not a functionality we need to offer). I know I can use the unhideable property on the column, but this simply removes them from the menu. Even if I set all columns as unhideable, the button is still there with an empty menu.

Apart from hiding it with CSS, which I did, is there a way to tell ColumnHider not to show that menu at all?

Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no programmatic way to completely hide the ColumnHider menu.  The simplest way is with CSS, e.g.:

```
.dgrid .dgrid-column-hider-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

It's also possible to just suppress a column from ColumnHider's list by adding `unhidable: true` to the column's definition.

However, it's not fully clear to me whether you even *need* the ColumnHider extension.  Regardless of what's in your actual data, if you don't want a particular field to be displayed in the grid, just don't define a column for it in `columns` (or whichever property you're using, e.g. `subRows` or `columnSets`).  You'll still have the full data item available to you e.g. for `renderCell` functions and if you extend `renderRow`.

Comment: I have the hidden column because in my page I want to show a selector with values for that column; when the selector changes value, I want to filter the store of the grid in order to show only those lines that have the selected value in the hidden column. Maybe there's a way to make a filter on the store without having the field represented in a column. I'll look into that. Thanks for the confirmation that there is no programmatical way to hide the button though.